# Potential consecutive days issue?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, profile-page, consecutive-days

I'm not entirely sure how the consecutive days logged in counter works on SO, but I believe there may be some bug in it. I've been logging into SO religiously for over a month now. Although I didn't make a new post every time I logged in, I at least perused the unanswered questions, checked my reputation, checked recent activity to see if anything I said before was up-voted...

Once before it completely forgot how many days I had logged in. I went to my profile to check and it said "32 days, 4 consecutive". A bit frustrated that I'd lost at least 20 consecutive days I considered immediately reporting the bug, but I figured it may have been my own fault. I couldn't remember what I was doing 4 days earlier and I may have missed day.

My browser history will now affirm the fact that I logged into SO yesterday, however, and today when I logged in it says "37 days, 1 consecutive".

I'm not sure if this is related to a bug in the consecutive days counter, a difference in timezone, or what. I live in the Eastern time zone and I tend to access SO from one of 3 different IP addresses (my home computer, campus, or my phone). I do not always access from each one every day (I never access from campus on the weekends and some days I only access from campus, not getting online when I get home).

Has anyone else had a related issue? Is this a known bug? Is this just the result of living in the Eastern timezone and logging in at 4pm one day then 9pm the next (29 hour difference) happens to put me just outside the midnight to midnight range?

It's really frustrating that I'm trying so hard for the fanatic badge and it keeps getting ripped away from me while I'm still so far...

Comment: If it helps, the UTC day starts at 8pm in your timezone (although on Sunday it's going to change to 7pm). You can see the current UTC time on your recent activity page (click the envelope in the top bar)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

StackOverflow is based on UTC time.  The 4pm + 29 hours = 9pm range you mentioned would put you outside a full UTC day.

Note that you can also click on your consecutive days in your profile to bring up a calendar.

Comment: So it is a timezone issue. Sad, but good to know now. I'll make sure I log in before 9pm every day.

Comment: Before 8pm every day, rather.