# Why does stack overflow get the day I'm visiting wrong?

Tags: support, activity-badges, visited-days

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Potential consecutive days issue?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/69472/potential-consecutive-days-issue)
>   [Why did my consecutive days disappear?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/55394/why-did-my-consecutive-days-disappear)

I have been working hard to earn my "Fanatic Badge." My count was up to almost 60 days. Usually I visit the site (always an internal page) earlier in the day (morning EST time). However this past Saturday I didn't visit the site until later in the day, more towards 6pm. But I most certainly visited during my day.

Now my counter only shows me at two consecutive days. Disappointing! This is wrong. SO should count by my days, not some universal day.

Is there anyway to get SO to recognize the hours of *my* days? Who do I appeal to to get this past Saturday properly counted?

Comment: Do you propose that they do it by time zone? That would be awfully complex. What if you moved your laptop to another time zone (as I have done a couple of times)? Would that be cheating?

Comment: @Robert Harvey: It's perfectly possible to accept it as a daily visit if it happens within say 32 hours. But yes, it would be more complex and prone to other bugs. @two7s: For this reason, if you want a a fanatic badge, log in morning *and* evening. :)

Comment: Badges?  BADGES?!  *We don't need no steenkin' BADGES!*

Comment: possible duplicate of [Potential consecutive days issue?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/69472/potential-consecutive-days-issue), [Why did my consecutive days disappear?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/55394/why-did-my-consecutive-days-disappear)

Comment: Mea culpa, I didn't search by "fanatic-badge" just added the tag after I asked the question. Thanks for all the down votes!

Comment: @Lennart: Exactly: to safely earn fanatic, log in roughly twice a day.  If you are a fanatic, this shouldn't be a problem.  :-)

Comment: Why is this guys question down-voted three times? Are we that intolerant here that you have to pound him down in votes?

Comment: @two7s_clash: I guess you're not a true fanatic, eh?

Comment: @Mehrdad: you ain't seen nothing yet, bub.

Comment: I say good for you for wanting the Fanatic badge.  If you _look forward_ to the next hundred days as days you might be able to answer another fun question, the time will go by, and before you know it, **you'll have your badge**.

Comment: @Rick: this is not a set back! I'm making it a point to be on here everyday **participating**. Glad to peel back another layer here, as it were, and delve deeper into the community. At least now I know what to expect when posting on meta; no slack! :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Now my counter only shows me at two consecutive days. Disappointing!

I feel your pain, but I'm afraid there's not much you can do about it now.

> This is wrong. SO should count by my days, not some universal day.

As others pointed out, even if they used Javascript or by some complex calculation from your location determined *your* timezone, you could easily cheat if you missed a day by moving your timezone to a timezone still in that day (e.g. [Baker Island, -12:00 UTC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTC%E2%88%9212:00)) and log in to "recover" your day.

(And before anyone suggests counter-cheating measures, realize that almost anything would negatively affect users who *legally* switched timezones, and then they would come on here to complain.)

Others have suggested the "day" could just be more lenient, i.e. 32 hours.  But that wouldn't be 100 visits in 100 days, would it?  **There's a reason why the Fanatic badge is a gold badge.**

There have been [other](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/89649/request-to-modify-requirements-for-fanatic-badge) attempts to get this to change with [good arguments](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/79995/get-rid-of-the-consecutive-days-requirement/80080#80080) against it.

> Is there anyway to get SO to recognize the hours of my days? Who do I appeal to to get this past Saturday properly counted?

As I said [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/89351/doesnt-logging-in-from-mobile-count-as-logging-in/89352#89352), there isn't much incentive for SE developers to do *anything* to restore the day based on any given appeal other than site outage.  It would require a manual database change based on digging through activity logs to make sure you really did visit based on some argument you are making that is actually contrary to the already-established rules.

That's a horribly time-consuming precedent to set considering how often this topic [comes up](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fanatic-badge).

Comment: Wouldn't it be quite fanatic to cheat? :-)

Answer (score 2):

Stack Exchange sites use UTC, not your local time. UTC currently ticks over at 8pm EDT. Others have complained about this before, without much movement.

Comment: It (currently) ticks over at 20:00 EST, or 8:00 PM if you prefer that notation. Unless you're in a very different EST, in which case I shall commence once again condemning the usage of matching 3 letter abbreviations in time zones.

Comment: @Grace: Yes. Oy. Changed.

Comment: @Grace It's so much shorter than "-4". ...wait :(

Comment: @Grace - http://www.timeanddate.com/library/abbreviations/timezones/ shows different time zones abbreviated to EST (each called "Eastern Standard Time"): Australian (UTC+10), Central American (UTC-5), Caribbean (UTC-5) and North American (UTC-5) [:-)

Comment: @Carlos To my luck, none of those happen to be UTC-10. But... I s'pose condemnation has to start sometime, doesn't it?

Answer (score 0):

SO uses UTC for all dates. Hence at 5pm in PST, it's already tomorrow.

Do you need to use your SO time log for something that makes this critical?

Comment: He stated why it was important - he was trying to get the Fanatic Badge (level of importance may vary, but to some, badges matter).

Comment: I bet at least 50% of SO users would give up their left leg to get +10000 rep...

Comment: Hmm, then maybe I should be offering bounties more often if it's really such a strong motivator.